# CKEditor: how to force P within DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

In the CMS I'm working on, I need to insert some custom HTML (which works):

```
var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml("<div class='sidebar'>Edit Sidebar Text</div>");
```

The problem is that when editing what's inside the sidebar element, pressing ENTER duplicates the sidebar DIV instead of adding a P tag within the sidebar. How do I tell the editor to use a paragraph instead?

I expect this:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    Enter sidebar text
<p></p>
</div>
```

and get this:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    Enter sidebar text</div>
<div class="sidebar">
    &nbsp;</div>
```

I have not made any changes to "entermode" settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost guessed the name of the preference:
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.forceEnterMode (yes I think that this setting should default to true, but at least we have the option to set it)

Comment: That's pretty close, except that now I get <p class="sidebar"> instead of <div class="sidebar">. I don't need the class name at all.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Alfonso's post, the second thing you need to do is insert your own paragraph as part of the wrapping element. That way CK will create a plain `<p>` tag inside the wrapper instead of `<p class="sidebar">`.

```
var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml("<div class='sidebar'><p>Edit Sidebar Text</p></div>");
```

Found this clue from here: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/inside